# DrillDown in UitableView using SplitView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I am creating a drilldown in UITableView using SplitView Template as done in mail.  From a tutorial I created the code that worked fine for a navigation based template.
I tried to modify it for a split view template.

```
    (void)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//Get the children of the present item.
        NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];
        if([Children count] == 0) {
        detailViewController.detailItem = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
        }
        else {

                  //Prepare to tableview.
                  RootViewController *rvController = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  //Increment the Current View
                  rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;
                  //Set the title;
                  rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
                  //Push the new table view on the stack
                 [COLOR="Red"][B] [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];[/B][/COLOR]
        rvController.tableDataSource = Children;
                  [rvController release];
        }
}
```

How do I have to change the code? The Line in Red is Crashing the Code. How do I Change my Code

---

I have solved my Query i am attaching the sample application if anybody want to achieve the same thing then my solution will point them at some path here is the link of the

iPhone Application : http://www.mediafire.com/?nszdqqdht9ceakb

iPad SplitView Application : http://www.mediafire.com/?861jggve88o8tp8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
```

to

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
```